# eBay API to fetch products and orders

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I want to fetch all the products and orders along with detailed info like SKU etc.

I tried inventory api to fetch products but it returns a count of 0. Upon google search, I found that it displays only those products that are created via the API and not the UI.

Can anyone share CURL request or point me to the API endpoint where i can get all products of the store along with the SKU and endpoint for getting order details as well?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.